# Group elements in ToolBar to overflow together

Tags: wpf, toolbar

I have a WPF `ToolBar` which overflows some of the child controls into its overflow panel when resized. How can I make it so that two particular adjacent controls will overflow together (meaning either both will be located in the overflow panel, or neither will).

For example, I'd like to keep the `TextBlock` and `ComboBox` always together in the following:

```
<ToolBar>
    <Button Content="button" />
    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Margin="3,0,3,0"
               Text="Size:" />
    <ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Center"
              ItemsSource="{Binding FontSizes}"
              Text="{Binding FontSize}"
              DataContext="{Binding}"
              IsEditable="True" />
</ToolBar>
```

One approach would be to place the controls in a `StackPanel`, but this ends up changing the styles for the controls in the toolbar, removing the nice toolbar styling for the controls. For some controls (or possibly even all controls) I can specifically set the style back to the "toolbar style" ... but I'm hoping there is a simpler approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You can also move that resource to your `ToolBarTray`.

```
<ToolBar>
    <ToolBar.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ComboBoxStyleKey}}" />
    </ToolBar.Resources>

    <Button Content="Button" />
                
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Content="Letter:" />
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" SelectedIndex="0" />
    </StackPanel>

</ToolBar>
```